# Ninject dependency for Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost v3.2.x

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, azure-web-roles, owin

I'm attempting to ninject ApiControllers in an Azure worker role. I've previously accomplished ninjection with the same controllers in an asp.net mvc 5 / web api 2 project in the same solution. Another non ninjected test controller in this WorkerRole project work and serve expected results.

While attempting to add the NuGet package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost (version 3.2.x) it looks like that package is ?erroneously? requiring a Ninject version ≥ 3.0.0.0 && < 3.1.0.0

I've tried

```
Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -ProjectName WorkerRole1
Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -Pre -ProjectName WorkerRole1
Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -Version 3.2.0 -ProjectName WorkerRole1
Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -Version 3.2.1-unstable-002 -ProjectName WorkerRole1
```

I was able to successfully add Ninject.Web.WebApi.SelfHost, however I believe I need the owin flavor and SelfHost didn't appear to install NinjectWebCommon.cs or equivalent. I don't know where to wire up ninject to the owin self host in the worker role once I am successful at including the OwinHost. I'm assuming it will be scaffold-ed in.

Result of attempting to install Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost

```
PM> Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -Pre -ProjectName WorkerRole1
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ninject.Web.WebApi (≥ 3.2.0-unstable)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ninject (≥ 3.2.0.0 && < 3.3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ninject.Web.Common (≥ 3.2.0.0 && < 3.3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (≥ 5.0 && < 6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.1.2 && < 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.1.2 && < 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.1.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost (≥ 3.0 && < 4.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation (≥ 3.0 && < 4.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ninject (≥ 3.0.0.0 && < 3.1.0.0)'.
Install-Package : Updating 'Ninject 3.2.2.0' to 'Ninject 3.0.1.10' failed. Unable to find versions of 'Ninject.Web.WebApi, Ninject.Web.Common' that are compatible with 'Ninject 3.0.1.10'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -Pre -ProjectName WorkerRole1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

Probably unrelated however in checking versions of installed package in the WorkerRole I note that a number of packages are IIS specific. Are these needed in an Azure WorkerRole Owin self host? And specifically for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost I see the following notation yet I do have Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost installed.

> This is a legacy package for hosting ASP.NET Web API within your own
>   process (outside of IIS). Please use the
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost package for new projects.

Installed packages in WorkerRole

```
PM> Get-Package -ProjectName WorkerRole1

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                                                               
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                                                               
EntityFramework                6.1.0                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.                                                                                                
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.0.0                Core interfaces for ASP.NET Identity.                                                                                                                                                   
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.E... 2.0.0                ASP.NET Identity providers that use Entity Framework.                                                                                                                                   
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi        5.0.0                This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on IIS. ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of client...
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.1.2                This package adds support for formatting and content negotiation to System.Net.Http. It includes support for JSON, XML, and form URL encoded data.                                      
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core   5.1.2                This package contains the core runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web API. This package is used by hosts of the ASP.NET Web API runtime. To host a Web API in IIS use the Microsoft.AspNe...
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin   5.1.2                This package allows you to host ASP.NET Web API within an OWIN server and provides access to additional OWIN features.                                                                  
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owi... 5.1.2                This package allows you to host ASP.NET Web API within your own process using the OWIN HttpListener server. ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services ...
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Sel... 5.1.2                This is a legacy package for hosting ASP.NET Web API within your own process (outside of IIS). Please use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost package for new projects.            
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... 5.0.0                This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on IIS. ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of client...
Microsoft.Data.Edm             5.6.1                Classes to represent, construct, parse, serialize and validate entity data models. Targets .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4.0, or .NET Portable Lib with support for .NET 4.0, SL 4.0, Win Pho...
Microsoft.Data.OData           5.6.1                Classes to serialize, deserialize and validate OData payloads. Enables construction of OData producers and consumers. Targets .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4.0 or .NET Portable Lib with sup...
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.1                LINQ-enabled client API for issuing OData queries and consuming OData payloads. Supports OData v3. Targets .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4.0 or .NET Portable Lib with support for .NET 4.5, ...
Microsoft.Owin                 2.1.0                Provides a set of helper types and abstractions for simplifying the creation of OWIN components.                                                                                        
Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics     2.1.0                Provides middleware components to assist in developing OWIN-based applications.                                                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpLis... 2.1.0                OWIN server built on the .NET Framework's HttpListener class. Currently the default server used for self-hosting.                                                                       
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting         2.1.0                Provides default infrastructure types for hosting and running OWIN-based applications.                                                                                                  
Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost        2.1.0                Includes components needed to host an OWIN-based application in a custom process.                                                                                                       
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Conf... 2.0.3                Windows Azure Configuration Manager provides a unified API to load configuration settings regardless of where the application is hosted - whether on-premises or in a Cloud Service.    
Newtonsoft.Json                6.0.2                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                                                                                                                          
Ninject                        3.2.2.0              Stop writing monolithic applications that make you feel like you have to move mountains to make the simplest of changes. Ninject helps you use the technique of dependency injection ...
Ninject.Web.Common             3.2.0.0              Bootstrapper for web projects                                                                                                                                                           
Ninject.Web.Common.Selfhost    3.2.0.0              Adds self hosting support to web common.                                                                                                                                                
Ninject.Web.WebApi             3.2.0.0              Extension for Ninject providing integration with ASP.NET MVC WebAPI 2                                                                                                                   
Ninject.Web.WebApi.Selfhost    3.2.0.0              Extension for Ninject providing integration with ASP.NET MVC WebAPI 2 Selfhost                                                                                                          
Owin                           1.0                  OWIN IAppBuilder startup interface                                                                                                                                                      
System.Spatial                 5.6.1                Contains classes and methods that facilitate geography and geometry spatial operations. Targets .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4.0 or .NET Portable Lib with support for .NET 4.0, SL 4.0, Win...
WindowsAzure.Storage           3.1.0.1              This client library enables working with the Windows Azure storage services which include the blob service for storing binary and text data, the table service for storing structured...

PM>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is late, but I ran into this same problem and found this question via a Google search.  I eventually got around it with `-DependencyVersion`:

```
Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost -DependencyVersion Highest
```

If you don't want to update all of the dependent NuGet packages, I found that manually installing all of the Ninject-related dependencies for Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost and then installing Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost also got around the issue.

Comment: This allowed the Install-Package to succeed. Haven't had any success finding documentation for the "-DependencyVersion Highest" in the nuGet docs. Was hoping one of the Ninject authors or maintainers might comment.

Comment: I can't to do this Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem today and I solved it by the following
add the following class implementation to your project

```
    public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
        {
            IResolutionRoot resolver;

            public NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
            {
                this.resolver = resolver;
            }

            public object GetService(Type serviceType)
            {
                if (resolver == null)
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has been disposed");

                return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
            }

            public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
            {
                if (resolver == null)
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has been disposed");

                return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                IDisposable disposable = resolver as IDisposable;
                if (disposable != null)
                    disposable.Dispose();

                resolver = null;
            }
        }

    // This class is the resolver, but it is also the global scope
    // so we derive from NinjectScope.

public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
{
    IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
        : base(kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
    }
}
```

2- then in NinjectWebCommon

add the following line of code  to this method CreateKernel():
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
so the complete implementation will be:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
           var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
                // Install our Ninject-based IDependencyResolver into the Web API config
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I tried this code my self and it works successfully